# How to use a header file without a cpp file

Tags: c++, header, global-variables, constants

I am a java developer, but I have had to learn C++ recently and I am confused about some things. What I would like to do is create a 'global' header file, which has a list of #define variables which will be constant throughout the suite I am creating. I created the header file, and I added some variables

```
#ifndef CONSTANTS_H
#define CONSTANTS_H

#define SM_START            1001;
#define SM_PAUSE            1002;
#define SM_STOP             1003;
#define SM_SAVE             1004;
#define SM_DISCARD          1005;
#define SM_SETUP            1007;


#endif // CONSTANTS_H
```

My problem is that I can't access these...

I have included the header file where I need it, but there is no way for me to access the constants inside of it. Do I **Have** to have a .cpp file? is there a way for me to access the constant variables?

Comment: In addition to the lovely comments below, please don't use #define for simple numeric constants if you can avoid it.  You can get the same effect and much easier error messages if you instead do `const int SM_START = 1001;` etc.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First: You shouldn't put the semicolons at the end of the `#define`. `#define` is a preprocessor directive, meaning that it basically does text replacement of the defined name with the content. So if you do something like `int a = SM_STOP + 1;` it would be preprocessed to `int a = 1003; + 1;` with your code, which is not what you want.

Second: Headers are generally not compiled themselves but only for inclusion into `*.cpp` files or other headers (where `#include` is once again a text substitution). Therefore, yes you need to have a `.cpp` file somewhere (well not exactly, first of all you can choose a different extension and second you could even give the compiler a header as compile unit, but I would advise against it, at least until you know what you are doing). However you do not need to have a `.cpp` file for your constants, just `#include` your header into whatever file you want to use the constants in.

Third: Why are you using preprocessor defines here? This seems to be like a perfect job for an enum. Then you could put it into a namespace/struct for removing the need to prefix them (with `SM_`). Or you could just use C++11's new `enum class`, which behaves much like java's enums. I would avoid preprocessors wherever possible. Since it is simply text replacement and it doesn't respect any scoping and such, which makes it easy to get into problems (like with your semicolons).

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that yuu have semicolons after `#define`. This is the only thing preventing you from using your "constants", which are not technically constants; they are *preprocessor definitions*.

Logically, the C++ compiler runs the text of your program through a preprocessor, a text filter that executes the directives starting in `#`. The `#define` directive instructs preprocessor to find all occurrences of its left part, and replace them verbatim with its right part. In your case, it includes semicolons, resulting in invalid expressions after replacement.

For example,

```
if (command == SM_DISCARD) ...
```

becomes

```
if (command == 1005;) ...
```

This is an error, and the compiler reports it as invalid syntax.

Answer (score 2):

Use `#include <constants.h>` or whatever your filename is to include this file. Also, you don't need the semi-colons. #defines are text replacements done on the code by the compiler.

Comment: "constants.h", not <constants.h> - The compiler is entitled not to recognise your includes if you put them in <>, and I've used more than one that would error this

Comment: @TomTanner Although you can use -I/path/to/include to circumvent that.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a `cpp` file. Including the header is enough.

The preprocessor expands your defines with whatever is after it.

`SM_START` will become `1001;`

So an expression like:

```
int x = SM_START;
```

will translate to

```
int x = 1001;;
```

which is still legal.

But that semicolon could lead to trouble in something like:

```
int x = SM_START * 10;
```

which will be expanded to:

```
int x = 1001; * 10;
```

which is obviously illegal.

Also, preprocessor directives are not to be confused with globals. Even though you probably shouldn't be using globals, using `#defines` is probably worse than defining a `class Global` or just using variables grouped in a `namespace`.

Comment: So is what I'm trying to do good practice? The idea is that this 'constants' will be made into a lib because more than one process will need to access it. If there is a better way to do this, please enlighten me because I am not sure if what I'm doing is right.

Comment: @PTBG not really. 1. globals are *generally* bad. 2. if you do use globals, put them as static const members in a class or as extern variables in a namespace.

Comment: @PTBG did you even read Grizzly's post. If it doesn't seem clear enough, ask him for more details. I found his answer very constructive. His last recommendation I repeat: use a C++11 enum class which is efficient enough and familiar to your coding experience in java.